# Why does doctrine 2.0 not support default column values?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

It appears that Doctrine 2.0 does not support any default values. What's is then the best solution for adding new columns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set default values on your entities:

```php
/** @Entity */
class SomeEntity {

    /** @Column(length=50) */
    private $someFieldWithDefault = 'defaultvalue';

    //...
}
```

Comment: that sounds easy enough. Thanks!